# Prove that $W_\lambda$ is a subspace of $R^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix, and let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue for $A$. The eigenspace of $A$ corresponding to $\lambda$ is the set
$$W_\lambda = \{x \in R^n : Ax = \lambda x\}$$

Prove that $W_\lambda$ is a subspace of $R^n$.

I am not sure how to prove that. Any known theorems I can make use of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to work straight from the definition of subspace.  All we have to do is show that
$W_\lambda = \{x \in \Bbb R^n : Ax = \lambda x \}$ satisfies the vector space axioms; we already know $W_\lambda \subset \Bbb R^n$, so if we show that it is a vector space in and of itself, we are done.  So, if $\alpha, \beta \in \Bbb R$ and $v, w \in W_\lambda$, then

$A(\alpha v + \beta w) = \alpha A v + \beta A w = \alpha \lambda v + \beta \lambda w = \lambda (\alpha v + \beta w), \tag{1}$

showing that $\alpha v + \beta w \in W_\lambda$; the other definitive properties of a vector space, commutativity of addition, existence of additive identity, properties of scalar multiplication, etc.,  apply to $W_\lambda$ *via* inheritance from $\Bbb R^n$; being closed under linear combination, as we have just seen,  this implies $W_\lambda$ is a subspace of $\Bbb R^n$.

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: That's exactly what @Alt said!

Comment: @ AcomPi:  yuppers, there really isn't much more which *can* be said about it!  I just said it all at once with $\alpha v + \beta w$; same math; different style!

Comment: Is it every the case that an eigenspace $W_{\lambda} = \mathbb{R}^n$? What prompted me to ask the question is that you detailed $W_{\lambda}$ as a proper subset of  $\mathbb{R}^n.$ Would it be more or not at all accurate to detail $W_{\lambda}$ simply as a subset (and not a proper subset), that is, as  $W_{\lambda} \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: @RafaelVergnaud:  When I typed $W_\lambda \subset \Bbb R^n$ I meant it in the broadest sense, allowing that $W_\lambda = \Bbb R^n$.  I always thought that "$\subset$" and "$\subseteq$" meant the same thing.  Certainly there are eigenspaces $W_\lambda \subsetneq \Bbb R^n$!  Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

### Hint:

Let $x,y\in W_\lambda$, then $x+y\in W_\lambda$ and $\alpha x\in W_\lambda$, for scalar $\alpha\in R$. Also $0 \in W_\lambda$.

Comment: Thanks a lot I totally forgot I could approach it this way. I was actually studying for an exam and this theorem was outside the material I had to study.